# Issue with element visibility when spamming with hover events

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

When I hover over `#HoverMe`, the `#hidden` shows, if I un-hover it, `#hidden` will disapear as intended. However, if I "spamming" with hover-unhover-hover-unhover really fast, it gets bugged so next time I hover `#HoverMe`, `#hidden`then just disappear instantly. I think there's some kind of timer-loop that mess it up? How do I prevent that?

```
$("#HoverMe").hover(function() {
    $("#hidden").show();
}, function() {
    $("#hidden").delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: `$("#hidden").stop(true,true).delay(1000).fadeOut();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stop(true)` to remove any queued animations before starting the next one:

```js
$("#HoverMe").hover(function() {
  $("#hidden").stop(true).show();
}, function() {
  $("#hidden").stop(true).delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="HoverMe">Hover me</div>
<div id="hidden">Not hidden!</div>
```

Comment: Works well, thanks! However I got an another question. While `#hidden` div is disappearing(when un-hover `#HoverMe`), how can I make it stop disappearing by hovering `#hidden` as well?  Like, hover `#HoverMe` to make it appear, and be able to stop it hiding by hovering `#hidden`. **Edit:** I tried to do same as above(   `$("#hidden").hover(function () { $(#hidden).Show()` without success.

Comment: You can put the `#hidden` element *inside* `#HoverMe`, or you can change the jQuery selector to `$('#HoverMe, #hidden')` so that you place the event on both elements